# Polymer Designer move "core-card" on button click

Tags: javascript, html, browser, polymer

I seem to be having some trouble getting a simple button in Polymer Designer to change the properties of a separate item. I want to make this button here:

```
<core-icon-button icon="more-vert" id="core_icon_button"></core-icon-button>
```

Move this "core-card" from "-10%" to "10%"

```
<core-card id="core_card" layout vertical left style="left:'-10%';">...</core-card>
```

I've tried multiple approaches to this, trying to use declarations like "{{...}}" etc. but I have had no luck figuring this out. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --core-card-left: -10%;
      }

      core-card {
        left: var(--core-card-left);
      }
    <style>
    <core-icon-button icon="more-vert" id="core_icon_button" on-click="updateLeft"></core-icon-button>
    <core-card id="core_card" layout vertical left style="left:'-10%';">...</core-card>

  </template>
```

```
  updateLeft = function(e) {
    this.customStyle['--core-card-left'] = '10%';
    this.updateStyles();
  };
```